# Returning list in async function in uwa vb.net

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, win-universal-app

I am trying to parse through some xml files and return the results to a datagrid in UWA. The code builds fine but when running it returns

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Festplatten_Archiv_Client.Drive]]' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

In my XAML.vb I am only calling the class to create the files and set the results as fileSource:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = Drive.Drives
End Sub
```

Which works fine if I only add a sample Drive with

```
drivelist.Add(New Drive("Name",0, 0, 0), "location", "date"))
```

But as I want to parse through the XMLs, this is my code.
This is my drives class:

```
 Public Shared Async Function Drives() As Task(Of List(Of Drive))
    Dim drivelist As New List(Of Drive)

    Dim folderpicked As StorageFolder
    Try
        folderpicked = Await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetItemAsync(ReadSetting("folderStorageToken"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Fehler: " & ex.Message)
        folderpicked = Nothing
    End Try


    Dim xmlfiles As List(Of StorageFile) = Await folderpicked.GetFilesAsync()
    For Each file In xmlfiles
    ''Process files
    Next

    Return Await Task.Run(Function() drivelist)
End Function
```

It might be something with async programming, but I am very new to this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'd need to `Await` `Drives()` when you call it.

Comment: I thought so too, but I am not allowed to await methods in the 'new sub' constructor like `dataGrid.ItemsSource = await Drive.Drives`  as it would require to make the function async

Comment: Then you need to assign the result of that `Drives` function (maybe give a function a name that doesn't sound like a property) to a variable of the appropriate type.  When the `Task<TResult>` completes, you can get its `Result` property and assign that to the `ItemSource` of your grid.

Comment: The alternative would be to not call that method in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a blocking call to an `Async` routine from the ctor as follows:

```
Dim drivesResult = Drives().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

This is effectively forcing the routine to execute synchronously.  If that's not what you want, then you'll need to explore a different alternative, e.g. the suggestion in the comments.